# Could this question be put off hold now?

Tags: support, request

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87249/electro-gravito-generator?noredirect=1#

I have edited the question to clarify the problem, but still it has been marked as question not clear and hold. Can it possibly be spared from the hold tag now ?

Answer (score 7):

You started off that post with

> Now I know that the site frowns on homebrew research

...I think you already should know why it's on hold/closed then.

Perpetual motion machines (and other similar devices like free energy machines) are (almost always) off topic on the main site because usually they arise from some flaw of assuming ideality. The same goes for yours. As I mentioned in response to your other post, original research isn't allowed, so even if the post is unclear, it should be closed as non mainstream.

Comment: I am not trying to prove a perpetual machine atleast not by disproving something such as energy conservation, on the contrary I am asking for help in applying energy conservation to find the source of energy.

Comment: @rijulgupta It is true that we do allow evaluations of research within the framework of established physics. However, this is not to say that the other rules don't apply. The localizedness of your question still holds, it and its answers won't really be useful to anyone else because there is very little chance of anyone else having the same problem.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and please do not just think that I am mad on basis of what I am saying next. If somehow my machine could not be disproven, I have not gotten any solid proof for the concept to be wrong not only here but even from some professors and teachers, all I got that it must not be possible, so if somehow it is proven this would be a tremendous change for all of us, I think it would actually be helpful. If in the end I find it to be no more than any other futile attempt at perpetual motion, I would be happy to remove the post.

Comment: I think its not of any help to put the question here, I will seek help elsewhere. Maybe one on one with some professor. Thanks for all your help anyway.

Comment: @Rijul: I gave a vague hint about how one can prove the impossibility of the device acting in the way you claimed. It mathematically follows that *if* electrostatics and gravity behave according to their usual $1/r^2$ laws, then it is impossible to gain energy during a mechanical cycle using *any* arrangement of moving mass and charge distributions. A detailed proof of this fact can be obtained by a careful application of theorems from vector calculus to the mechanics of motion.

Comment: Exactly, the entire point of physics is that it's consistent. If we prove a general result, we don't need to check the specific cases except to verify the general result.

Comment: Can somebody somehow prove it wrong ? I have discussed with this a few professors and the response was that it should not be possible, I am still getting the same here. Even I know that according to established physics it should not be possible, but the problem is that the results say something else. Please comment if you have something else to add than to say that it is not or should not be possible.

Comment: @rijulgupta I suspect you're not running your simulations correctly. With the current information you've given, there's nothing _wrong_ with it, but it doesn't seem to generate energy either. Again, I suspect you're making a mistake when looking at torques rather than tracking the velocities. If you want to discuss further, come to [chat]

Answer (score 4):

I can think of an analogous *on*-topic question about *perpetuum mobiles*, which was phrased in a way that did *not* bring in non-mainstream physics: [What prevents this magnetic perpetuum mobile from working?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75471/what-prevents-this-magnetic-perpetuum-mobile-from-working/). Three points to note for this:

- That question is on topic, and it got good answers, mostly because of the tone it was asked in. If you're asking us to do your work, then we probably have more interesting things to do. If you present us with an interesting puzzle, then some of us will be more interested.
- Additionally, that question makes it clear that this is within mainstream physics. Perpetuum mobile proposals are off-topic in this site because they always have, and always will, turn out hollow. If you're trying to convince us that yours works, you're barking up the wrong tree, and our patience is likely to run short quite quickly.
- The method given in my answer, and the associated physics, will to hold in a modified form for the device you propose. The electrostatic and gravitational fields are conservative, so your pendulum bob will respond to some specific, conservative, potential energy landscape, which is on you to calculate. You will *not* be able to harvest energy simply from gravitational and electrostatic forces.

Having said this, I have little interest in following up on your proposal. As DumspterDoofus explained, there's a general theorem that disqualifies your device. You're doing something wrong and it's on you to figure out what.